# is it possible to create a shared file in internal storage between two application?

Tags: android, android-service

I would like to create two applications, the first creat and write in a file. the Second one read from this file and update its informations. I  don't know if it is possible. and if it is  possible for the update the best way is a service or an Activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) to provide access for third party apps to your internal files. This is the recommended method for sharing files across apps, and is much safer as pointed out by @CommonsWare in the comments.

If you are the one writing both apps, and they are signed with the same key, then you can also use a [shared user ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) to allow direct interapp access to data files.

Comment: Of the two, `ContentProvider` is *much* safer.